# log4j2 - set file path from properties issue

Tags: java, spring, log4j2

I just converted from log4j to log4j2, using an xml config file. Everything is working except that I can't seem to set the path of my log files using a properties file.

This is a Spring MVC app and I have a `filedirs.properties` file located in the `src/main/resources` folder along with the log4j2.xml, i18n message and other properties files.  It has a simple entry: `logs=G:/web/logs/`.` I've looked through other posts and am just not getting how to configure log4j2 correctly. Here's what I've have:

```
<Configuration>
<Properties>
    <Property name="filename">${bundle:net.myapp.filedirs:logs}standard.log</Property>
</Properties>
<File name="stdLog" fileName="${filename}" ignoreExceptions="false">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DEFAULT} %-5p: %c - %m%n"/>
</File>
...rest of config...
```

The error is this:

```
ERROR FileManager (${bundle:net.myapp.filedir:logs}standard.log) java.io.FileNotFoundException:
```

Substituting the actual path works, e.g.,

`<Property name="filename">g:/web/logs/standard.log</Property>`

I'm hung up on the correct domain portion of the bundle syntax - myapp.net is not the actual website, but it's similar enough.  I've tried a couple dozen variations but in debug mode java.util.ResourceBundle never finds the filedirs properties file when it goes through the log4j2 initialization. The manual sample is `com.domain.messages` so I'm stumped why `net.myapp.filedirs` doesn't work.

Comment: I recommend raising this on the log4j2 issue tracker

Comment: @Remko Popma, are you saying that this should work as I've described?  I'm still relatively new to Java and Spring so I figured I made a newbie mistake or misunderstood how it's supposed to work...

Comment: They'll be happy to help either way.

Comment: Well, I figured it out.  I found there is a status=debug setting at the <Configuration> level which I turned on. I also went back into debugging the ResourceBundle and FileAppender classes. One thing I noticed in the configuration debug messages is that the context was set to my domain, "myapp", so I tired the one bundle config I hadn't tried earlier: '<Property name="filename">${bundle:filedir:logs}standard.log</Property>'. This worked!  So it appears that the documentation is wrong?  I spent nearly the entire day on this - not a happy camper...

Comment: Would you mind raising this on the Log4j2 Jira issue tracker? I noticed that the manual page for Lookups (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html) doesn't even mention resource bundle lookups...

Comment: No problem.  I was going off of the Property Substitution section for guidance on this: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I indicated in my comment, it turns out that it does work but the manual may be incorrect. Instead of `com.domain.messages` as described here, [Property Substitution](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution), what worked was simply `messages`, e.g., `<Property name="filename">${bundle:filedir:logs}standard.log</Property>`. Adding `status=debug` to `<Configuration>` finally helped me figure this out.

I don't know if this makes any difference, but I'm testing through STS (`localhost`) on my PC - is it possible the documentation may be correct for a production website? No idea since I don't have a production deployment yet but it's something I'll check out when I get it up and running.