# How to set log file path dynamically in log4j2.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I have done logging using log4j2 in spring-boot. I want set the log file path dynamically from properties file. I have written the below code for that, But it is not working fine.

my properties file **abc.properties** code is the following

```
log4j2FilePath = logs/log4j2-demo.log
```

and my log file **log4j2.xml** code is the following

```
 <Property name="log-path">config.properties.log4j2FilePath</Property>

        <RollingFile name="FileAppender" fileName="${log-path}"
                     filePattern="logs/log4j2-demo-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
```

Comment: I got the answer from the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35386080/log4j2-set-file-path-from-properties-issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [log4j2 - set file path from properties issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35386080/log4j2-set-file-path-from-properties-issue)

Answer (score 1):

By default **log4j2** looks for declared dynamic properties in **log4j2.properties** file.
If you wish to use some other property file, let's say **abc.properties**, I would suggest using proxy variables. 
By this I mean, you can create a variable in **log4j2.properties** which actually gets the value from **abc.properties**. 
So you can access variable in **log4j2.properties** like this,

```
property.fileName=${bundle:abc:log.path}
```

Answer (score 0):

**abc.properties**

log4j2FilePath=logs/log4j2-demo.log

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">${bundle:abc:log4j2FilePath}</Property>
</Properties>
```

Comment: what do you mean by bundle ?

Comment: @Santhosh Kumar  Where you defined this bundle, Can you please specify that too.

Comment: @vijesh No need to define the "bundle", It just indicates the properties file implicitly

Answer (score 0):

By default `spring-boot` is looking for `logback.xml` (or `logback-spring.xml`) into your project resources folder.
If you want to use dynamicly generated settings you can override property into your `application.properties` file `logging.config=/some/path/logging-settings.xml`

All `logging.*` properties are part of [LoggingApplicationListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/logging/LoggingApplicationListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean 'programmatically' by the word 'dynamically' then here is the solution.

add the below line in log4j2.properties file

```
appender.rolling.fileName = ${sys:logFilePath}/logger.log
```

and in java set system properties as below

```
System.setProperty("logFilePath", "path to the log folder");
```

I am new in log4j2 and I use .properties file. So I am not sure what is the equivalent of `appender.rolling.fileName` in xml.